# Run react app in electron but not on localhost

Tags: reactjs, localhost, electron

Is there any way to prevent accessing the app through localhost?
It should only be seen inside the electron app so if you navigate to localhost:3000 it should display "Can't reach website".

At the moment npm start calls     `"start": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none yarn react-scripts start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\"",`, which doesn't open a new browser window on localhost:3000, but if you do that manually it still shows the same content as it does in the electron app.